# Algebra Lecture notes

Tags: soft-question, lecture-notes

The question is very simple: are there good Algebra online lecture notes for a first year course (one semester, US) satisfying the following constraints.

-They cover basics on groups and rings

-They are freely available online

-They contain many exercises (5-10 ex per week)

Comment: This is an opinion-only question that's likely to be closed. I suggest you  look at several online notes (easy to find with a search) and see which meet your weighting of content and difficulty. You can't optimize everything simultaneously.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221196/big-list-free-textbooks-and-resources may interest you

Comment: @Ethan Bolker removed the "opinion" part. Now I just ask for lecture notes under these constraints.

Comment: @Reyx_0 what even is algebra 1? I may have books on it but I am not too sure if I know what *you* are studying. Please list anything in your syllabus so I can inform you if I have anything on it.

Comment: Guys, I am the lecturer here and I want to select something freely available which also covers the needed material. Algebra 1 is the first course in Algebra you do at university and usually contains basics on groups and rings.