# I'm looking for a book with solved exercises on differential geometry of surfaces (Christoffel symbols, cutvatures, etc.)

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I'm very bad at long and tedious calculations and I need to cruch through at least 10 to be able to do it quickly enough to pass a test, so I'm looking for such calculations heavy exercises with solutions to make sure i do it right.

Do you know any books that would fit my description?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221196/big-list-free-textbooks-and-resources may have something for you.